# Getting live keyboard strokes to execute function in C

Tags: c

I am working on what I believe should be a simple program I have googled around and all I can find is stuff for C#, C++.

What I would like to accomplish is to start my program written in `C` and have it listen for certain keystrokes. I have a function written that will move a servo so I would like to integrate the Up and Down arrow keys to execute the function to move the servo one direction or the other. Is this possible in `C`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but not with std C, what you want to do is OS specific. What is your targeted system?

Comment: If you are speaking about linux, there's a lot of libraries that allow you to do so. Or even you can read `/dev/input/eventX` directly.

Comment: Yes I am using linux `Raspbian` to be exact

Comment: I dont know if it works for linux, but for windows I used getch(). when you press an special key first you get one char (special) and the if you ask again you get the code of the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you working on linux or windows? Based on that, there are alternatives that can be used.
If you are working on windows, a function should be familiar to you : kbhit()? Though it is now deprecated, the working knowledge of it could be useful :)
Assuming that you are working on linux, have you tried NCurses?

Taken from [Here]: (http://www.linuxmisc.com/9-unix-programmer/d5b30f8d1faf8d82.htm)

The problem is three-fold:

1. You have to check if data is available without blocking. A simple
   'read' or fgets' or whatever will block your process until data is
   available -- you don't want that.
2. You have to bypass any buffering
   because otherwise you would have to   check both the buffer and the
   device.
3. You need to coerce the terminal driver to give you data as
   it's   available rather than accumulating the whole thing into a
   line.

From the same page:

That said, I present the following awkward, hastily-written, 
uncommented code, which may be instructive or may not ( edited in part by me, was missing parenthesis and not indented)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <termios.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 

static struct termios orig_term; 
void u_cleanup(void) 
{ 
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &orig_term); 
}
int u_kbhit(void) 
{ 
    struct termios t; 
    int ret; 
    fd_set rfd; 
    struct timeval to; 
    static int first_hit=0; 
    if(first_hit==0) 
    { 
        if(tcgetattr(0, &t)!=0) exit(0); 
        orig_term=t; 
        cfmakeraw(&t); 
        if(tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t)!=0) exit(0); 
        atexit(u_cleanup); 
        first_hit=1; 
    } 

    FD_ZERO(&rfd); 
    FD_SET(0, &rfd); 
    to.tv_sec=0; 
    to.tv_usec=0; 
    if(select(1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &to)==1) return 1; 
    return 0; 
}
int u_getchar(void) 
{ 
    int ret; 
    fd_set rfc; 
    unsigned char buf; 
    if(read(0, &buf, 1)!=1) ret=0; 
    else ret=buf; 
    return ret; 
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    while(1) 
    { 
        if(u_kbhit()) 
        { 
            int key=u_getchar(); 
            printf("hit: %d\r\n", key); 
            if(key==3) 
            { 
                printf("you hit control-c\r\n"); 
                exit(0);                         
            }         
        } 
        usleep(100); 
    }
    return 0; // inaccessible code, to prevent compiler warning
 }
```